# Unity not finding all classes

Tags: c#, unity-container

I have several Job projects, each with a single job declared in it.  Each job is declared to inherit from an `IJob<IJobPayload>` interface.  I have another application that does NOT reference any of these projects, but must be able to use them.  To that end, I am scanning a directory for all projects that match a known naming convention.  I then do some manipulation and try to register them in Unity.

```
var container = UnityConfig.GetConfiguredContainer();
var path = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
var files = Directory.GetFiles(path, "QueueApp.Job.*.dll");
var allAssemblies = files.Select(Assembly.LoadFile).ToList();
var jobAssemblies = AllClasses.FromAssemblies(allAssemblies);
var jobTypes = jobAssemblies.Where(type => typeof(IJob).IsAssignableFrom(type) && type.IsClass);

container.RegisterTypes(
    jobTypes,
    WithMappings.FromAllInterfaces,
    WithName.Default,
    WithLifetime.ContainerControlled);
```

The `files` collection shows 6 DLLs found.
The `allAssemblies` collection shows 6 assemblies
The `jobAssemblies` collection shows 4 items, none of them are classes based on IJob!
The `jobTypes` is empty!

I am not seeing what I am doing wrong.

Let me build this up from the bottom:

```
public interface IJob<TPayload> : IJob where TPayload : IJobPayload
{
    JobType JobType { get; }
    JobInfoPayload JobInfo { get; }
    TPayload Payload { get; set; }
    string PayloadAsString { get; set; }
    string Execute(IServerFilter jobContext, string payload, IJobCancellationToken cancellationToken);
    bool CachePut();
    bool CacheGet();
    bool CacheExists();
}
```

Base class:

```
public class BaseJob<TPayload> : IEventSource where TPayload : IJobPayload
{
    protected internal IJobExecutor<TPayload>[] Executors;
    public JobInfoPayload JobInfo => Payload.JobInfo;
    public TPayload Payload { get; set; }
    public string PayloadAsString
    {
        get { return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Payload); }
        set { Payload = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TPayload>(value); }
    }
    protected internal readonly List<IEvent> Events = new List<IEvent>();

    public string Execute(IServerFilter jobContext, IJobCancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        // TODO: setup bus handler definitions here...

        while (Payload.JobInfo.JobStatus != JobStatus.Done)
        {
            var jobStrategy = new JobExecutorStrategy<TPayload>(Executors);
            Payload = jobStrategy.Execute(Payload);

            if (Payload.JobInfo.JobStatus == JobStatus.Handoff)
                break;
        }
        return PayloadAsString;
    }

    public bool CachePut()
    {
    }
    public bool CacheGet()
    {
    }
    public bool CacheExists()
    {
    }

    public IEnumerable<IEvent> GetEvents()
    {
        return Events;
    }

    public void Clear()
    {
        Events.Clear();
    }
}
```

Sample Job Class:

```
public class JobPingPong : BaseJob<JobPingPong.PayloadModel>, IJob<JobPingPong.PayloadModel>
{
    public JobType JobType => JobType.AdHoc;

    /// <summary>
    /// Additional fields for the PAYLOAD required to run job...
    /// </summary>
    public class PayloadModel : MinimumPayload
    {
        public string[] Tokens { get; set; }
        public int GenericIntId { get; set; }
        public string GenericStringId { get; set; }
    }

    public JobPingPong()
    {
        Executors = new IJobExecutor<PayloadModel>[]
        {
            new Initialize(this),
            new Processing(this),
            new Complete(this),
            new ExtComplete(this),
            new ExtError(this),
            new Error(this)
        };
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Overrides the base class method so we can decorate with a specific set of attributes: DisableConcurrentExecution, QueueName
    /// </summary>
    /// <seealso cref="https://github.com/HangfireIO/Hangfire/issues/245"/>
    /// <param name="jobContext"></param>
    /// <param name="payload"></param>
    /// <param name="cancellationToken"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    [DisableConcurrentExecution(30)]
    [Queue("serial")]
    public string Execute(IServerFilter jobContext, string payload, IJobCancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        PayloadAsString = payload;
        return base.Execute(jobContext, cancellationToken);
    }
}
```

When I try to get this into Unity, all I am seeing is the child class `JobPingPong.Payload` but not finding the class `JobPingPong`.  What obvious thing am I missing?  I don't need any of the `IJobPayload` classes in Unity, just the `IJob` based classes.

---

ADDITIONAL INFO:  I added this code to see if I could get to where I want.  While it did register the IJob, it did not register as the concrete class.

```
var dependencies = Directory.GetFiles(@"D:\...\Development\QueueApp\Source\QueueApp.Job.TestPingPong\bin\Debug", "QueueApp.Job.*.dll");

var pluginMappings = new Dictionary<Type, Type>();

//Load Dependency Assemblies
foreach (string fileName in dependencies)
{
    if (fileName.Contains("Batc.QueueApp.Job.Core")) continue;
    var pluginAssembly = Assembly.LoadFrom(fileName);
    var pluginTypeList = pluginAssembly.GetTypes();
    foreach (var pluginType in pluginTypeList)
    {
        if (!pluginType.IsPublic || pluginType.IsAbstract) continue;

        //Gets a type object of the interface we need the plugins to match
        var typeInterfaces = pluginType.GetInterfaces();
        foreach (var typeInterface in typeInterfaces)
        {
            if (pluginMappings.ContainsKey(typeInterface)) continue;
            pluginMappings.Add(typeInterface, pluginType);
        }
    }
}

//Web API resolve dependencies with Unity
var container = Dependency.UnityConfig.GetConfiguredContainer();
pluginMappings.ForEach(mapping => container.RegisterType(mapping.Key, mapping.Value));
```

Comment: Not an answer, but you could try the well tested `Type.ByImplementedInterfaceInDirectory(string directory, string wildcard)` in [Productivity Extensions](https://github.com/peteraritchie/ProductivityExtensions) via https://www.nuget.org/packages/ProductivityExtensions/ to see if that operates differently

Comment: How do you use this correctly?  To get a type, I've already done the path, wildcard, assembly, all leading to a type.  Then, using that type I use this extension?

Comment: With your type, something like `var jobTypes = typeof(IJob).ByImplementedInterfaceInDirectory(path, "QueueApp.Job.*.dll");`

Comment: That's what I ended up doing.  Still pulls back 0 hits.  Will keep working on it.

Comment: Weird, are they public classes?

Comment: Yes, definitely.  (Added some additional info above)

Comment: `typeof(IJob)` would generate an error if `IJob` is really generic; maybe there's something you haven't detailed behind the problem.